# Plone 4.3.3 and EEA Faceted Navigation

Tags: collections, plone

I have several collections that are created by combinations of different Tags, which are working fine with the default Collections from Plone 4.3.3. But as soon as I enable faceted navigation in the collection it seems to forget the query of the collection and its results. Instead it displays every possible item.

Did I miss something in the configuration? Do I need to make the "pre"-query with faceted navigation too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EEA Faceted Navigation is aware of old style Collection **(Topic) query**. Unfortunately nobody noticed that it doesn't support new-style Collections until now or something has changed within the latest releases of plone.app.collection.

I've already added a ticket for this issue. Please follow progress at https://github.com/eea/eea.facetednavigation/issues/52